# MySQL/Hibernate retrieving wrong data with column mapped as LocalTime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm mapping a `TIME` column of a MySQL database in Hibernate (`5.4.6.Final`) as a `java.time.LocalTime` class.
This is the declaration of the mapping into the entity:

```
@Column(name = "TIMEVAL")
public LocalTime TIMEVAL;
```

The column in the database has value `00:30:00`, however Hibernate it's building the instance of `TIMEVAL` with a value of `01:30:00`.
I thought about a difference of time-zones (Ignoring the fact that the TIME data-type doesn't have a time-zone) between the server and the hibernate connection, but I setup each connection and the server as UTC.
And by executing the queries:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

The result of the Hibernate session and the server were all `+00:00`.
Following the Hibernate configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/..?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowMultiQueries=true
```

And here's the MySQL configuration:

```
default-time-zone=+00:00
```

I tried also:

1. Specifying the MySQL column as `VARCHAR(8)`, but Hibernate always retrieves `01:30:00`;
2. Changing the Entity data-type to `Duration`, but Hibernate throws an error saying that it can't map TIME to java.lang.Long.

What do I need to modify in order to have Hibernate build the `LocalTime` instance with the value of the database column?

Comment: What is the Java time zone, i.e. [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--)? --- Without anything saying otherwise, the *local* time is local to the JVM, right?

Comment: @Andreas printing the result of that method returns `Europe/Berlin`. Yes, I suppose too.. So i need to change the JVM default/system zone to UTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andreas pointed out in the comments. The JVM time zone wasn't in UTC.
I needed to change the JVM time zone to get the correct value out of the database.
So, by adding the following param to the JVM options:

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Finally the `LocalTime` instance was built with the value of `00:30:00` as the value of the database column.